# Is it possible to pass flags in to regex_matches with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to select multiple matches from a field, I have the query working as SQL but am at a loss when it comes to the jOOQ version. Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT
  array_to_string(array(select array_to_string(regexp_matches(m.content, '#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'g'), ' ')), ' ') hashtags
FROM tweets
```

But I can't work out how to pass in the `'g'` flag to `regexp_matches`, and Postgres doesn't support `g:` style embedded flags. At the moment I'm using (in Scala):

```scala
val hashtags = DSL.field(
  "array_to_string(array(select array_to_string(regexp_matches(tweets.content, '#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'g'), ' ')), ' ')",
  classOf[String])
```

but that seems kind of gross (but it works, so there's that! ).

### Current Approach

I have an enum with fields associated with it, like this:

```
MentionUri(MENTIONS.URL),
Content(MENTIONS.CONTENT),
Hashtags(DSL.field(
  "array(select array_to_string(regexp_matches(mentions.content, '#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'g'), ' '))").as("hashtags")),
MediaLinks(DSL.field("json_agg(twitter_media)").as("media_links")),
Location(MENTIONS.LOCATION),
```

the 'g' flag is needed because I want to get *all* of the matching fragments from the target text (all of the hashtags from the mention content in this case, where mentions are Tweets, Facebook posts, &c.)

and a class with a bunch of optional search parameters, like this:

```scala
minFollowing: Option[Int] = None,
maxFollowing: Option[Int] = None,
workflowStates: Set[WorkflowState] = WorkflowState.values.toSet,
onlyVerifiedUsers: Boolean = false,
```

and then I build up the query based on a list of these fields

```scala
private val fields = v.fields.toSet
override def query(sql: DSLContext): Query = {
  val fields = v.fields.map(_.field) ++ Seq(M.PROJECT_ID)
  var query = (sql
    select fields.toSet.asJava
    from M
    leftJoin MTM on (M.PROJECT_ID === MTM.PROJECT_ID) and (M.ID === MTM.MENTION_ID)
    leftJoin TM on (MTM.URL === TM.URL)
    where (M.PROJECT_ID in v.criteria.projectIds.asJava))
  if (v.criteria.channels.size < numChannels)
    query = query and (M.CHANNEL in v.criteria.channels.asJava)
  if (v.criteria.mentionTypes.size < numMentionTypes)
    query = query and (M.MENTION_TYPE in v.criteria.mentionTypes.asJava)
  // ... more critera get added here, finally ...
  if (v.max.isDefined)
    query groupBy (M.PROJECT_ID, M.ID, M.CHANNEL, M.USERNAME) limit v.max.get
  else
    query groupBy (M.PROJECT_ID, M.ID, M.CHANNEL, M.USERNAME)
```

Comment: What's the jOOQ query you've got so far? And in particular: why is passing the `'g'` flag the issue here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm lost now. What is really your question here? The fact that you find your plain SQL usage "gross"?

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid having to use any plain SQL. TBH it's not a huge issue as there are only a couple of places in my app where I do, and I can probably even get rid of those by defining a function and using that.

Comment: OK. So, is there still something I can help you with? :)

Comment: No, I think I'm OK with what I have. Thanks!